# Refresh contents of another app from within my app

Tags: android, multithreading

This is not a question of launching another app, though that is a hack I found.

I have two apps, I'll call them M for My app that I created and O for Other App that I downloaded from the PlayStore. Also there's D, somewhere that data is stored.

M fetches data from D and O stores data in D. 
For M to be of any use to me, I need the data to be up to date, which happens only when O is in foreground from my observation.

What would be the best way to do this?
I have tried ensuring that O is not battery optimized. (Background processes are not killed), but that did not help in refreshing content of D.

Another workaround I found is:

```
Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
```

where packageName is of O.
However, I do not know how to come back to my app, and this seems like a bad idea to me.

Please note: I cannot have any button clicks, as this entire process needs to run without manual intervention once O is running.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way should be `BroadcastReceiver` but if another app is from play store please check when it updates the Data does it "Broadcast" something, if yes then you can Register a `BroadcastReceiver` for that and you will get notified in `onRecieve` of broadcastReceiver.

If Other app do not broadcast any thing then you may not know when it updating the data, in that case you have to check data source periodically to check for updates.

Comment: I don't have much experience with this. How do I check if the app is broadcasting?

Comment: can you please tell what application you are using as "O" and at what point you want to get update to "M"?

Comment: I'm using Sony Smartband2 app. And I want an instant update to M.

Comment: You can refer to this blog: https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/make-your-app-work-with-android-wear-in-4-easy-steps

It is how communication happens between wear and android device,  but I am not sure about how to get notified in case of other app.

Comment: This is related to Android wear, I have no control over my band, (This is a fitness tracker, not a smartwatch) so this is of no use. Thanks anyway